# DataGrid Selection changing when cell contains Extended ListBox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, listbox, selectionchanged

I have a DataGrid.  Within one of the cell's of the DataGrid is a ListBox with its property set to extended.  When I first select an item in the listbox, the row for the DataGrid gets selected.  However, if I want to multi-select another item in the listbox,  I hold down CTRL and click on the other item.  At that point, the row of my grid becomes de-selected.
Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening.

I found a solution using the Dispatcher where I reset the selected item, but that causes the item to have an unsettling flicker.
I have tried setting the Handled flag to true in various places, but that either doesn't prevent the unwanted behavior, or the listbox loses the ability to select any items.

Does anybody have any better solutions?

Comment: Are you doing the listbox in a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: Yes.  That is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: The only way I could get multi-select to work without the row deselecting was by setting the SelectionMode="Multiple" for the listbox.  Otherwise, if you follow the events, the datagrid is actually deselecting after you Ctrl+Click and then reselecting with each Ctrl-Click.  I would report a bug with the WPF team.